# Searching for patterns of strings in a text

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search

I'm trying to write a program in Java that looks for patterns of strings inside a text file.
Consider the following text, taken from a novel:

*She was a very awesome woman, he thought. Then she said: "Hello, my name's Lauren. What's yours?"*

I'd like to find a way to find any occurrence of this sequence of words: HELLO , any string, NAME (taken from a list), so that, from the example above, I would get (in bold):

*She was a very awesome woman, he thought. Then she said: "**Hello, my name's Lauren**. What's yours?"*

At first I thought about using regex, then I considered writing a parser (maybe a JFlex or ANTRL generated one).

Anyone knows about an easier, and hopefully quicker to code, solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) to tag parts of sentences, and then fetch those sentences with the criterias that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems very fitting with my task. I'm going to study stanford POS tagger in details. Btw, have you ever used it? If so,have you ever created a custom tagger file? Thanks again.

Comment: You won't need a custom tagger file I suppose..just study the tag set used in the tagger properly,and you will be able to achieve what you want..for instance,in the example you have given,hello will fall under a specific tag,a name will fall under proper noun..study the tag set and you should do fine..to further saturate your searches,try clubbing the tagger with Pattern and Matcher,using your specific regex Patterns..good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think that a Regular Expression using the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class is your best bet if you are simply trying to match HELLO (case-insensitive), any string, Name (taken from a list).

Take a look at an online RegEx evaluator to build your expression (like http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).  It will take you a bit of work to build the expression, but once you do it will provide a concise way to express your string searching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), the Java search engine.  You need something that will understand n-grams.